# Creating a file from a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin that needs to be able save a file. What is the best way to do this without worrying about file permissions. (i.e Is there a directory that is considered safe to write to?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can upload images to your blog, then `wp-content/uploads` should be writable.

But file permissions are always something to worry a little about when you're deploying to a new server.

Comment: the only thing I wasn't sure about when writing to that dir was that I didn't know if the structure of that folder changed and if I had to worry about my directory being wiped

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can create a directory with `mkdir()`, mermissions to `chmod(777)` so you can delete this directory from ftp without a root user and this dir will bee fully writable via php. And also `chmod` you files with 777, otherwise you can't delete without root permissions.

Comment: `var_dump(mkdir(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my_plugin/my_dir', 0777));` always returns `false`. The directory that contains the new directory must have writable permissions for everyone and it's not realistic to have the user change their permissions.

Comment: Does the dir "my_plugin" exists? If not you have to create it. Simplest way is to use recuresive creation, with mkdir setting 3rd parameter to true: `mkdir(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my_plugin/my_dir', 0777, TRUE)`

Comment: it does exist, but the permissions are `755` which aren't right for writing from php, and that is going to be the case probably 99% of the time. The only time it wouldn't be the case is if the user changed it but the user is most likely not even going to know where to start.

Comment: Not sure, bau MAYBE you can use `session_save_path()` ? Alsu i guess you can write in `sys_get_temp_dir()`, but on both i'n not sure you can and how long these files will stay.

Comment: Well, those dirs wouldn't work for my use as this file needs to always be available to the public.